# Range query with non-clustered index, including all of the queried fields, runs much faster than the same query with clustered index

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

We are loading big amounts of data (~200 million rows, ~10GB in size) from SQL Server. The server is SQL Server 2019, running on a Linux machine, with plenty of memory and very fast network. The data is later processed by Spark application, but that doesn't matter, we get the same results with a test application.

The table we're querying is very wide, it has about 100 columns, and the query selects some of those columns, based on the time range. And, since we're running it from Spark, it is distributed among executors and additional time filter is added.

Something like:

```
select * 
from 
    (select time, col1, col5, col38 
     from table 
     where time > '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
       and time <= '2020-02-01 00:00:00.000') subq 
where time > '2020-01-05 00:00:00.000' 
  and time <= '2020-01-06 00:00:00.000'
```

Initially, the table had only the unique clustered index (same as PK) on `id` (not used in our queries, but essential for other usages) and `time`, in that specific order. That, of course, gave us unacceptable results, like hours of loading time.

After we've added non-clustered index on the time column, the timings significantly improved, the loading started to take about 30-40 minutes.

Then we added all the queried columns to the non-clustered index, as 'included' columns. The performance improved dramatically, now that specific query completes in 20-30 seconds!

However, the problem here is that we don't know the exact columns in advance, there can be (almost) any combination of them. And building a new index takes hours.

So, we thought that non-clustered index on the time column with all included columns is essentially the same as the clustered index on time column, we've created a copy of the table with clustered index on (time, id), i.e. changed the order of columns in the clustered index. We were expecting that the performance will be the same as for the non-clustered index, but not - it still takes a lot of time.

When we run the single query in the Query Analyzer, it returns immediately, and the query plan shows that clustered index seek is used.

So, the questions are - why the clustered index behaves so badly, and are there any other ways, except of creating non-clustered index with all columns included, to get the good performance?

EDIT: I've checked the SQL Profiler output - the queries use the indexes exactly as they are supposed to do - the fast one uses non-clustered seek, the slow one uses clustered seek. There are no other steps in the plan - the query is really simple. Both of the queries show approximately the same CPU counter, but the slow (clustered) one makes 10 times more reads.

Comment: I think your definition of big is fact rather small.

Comment: Will it improve performance if I'll treat it as small?
Anyway, this is a development system, the real data is expected to be at least 10 times more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Short version - Something doesn't sound correct.

- If, when running the command via SSMS and it does a clustered index seek, I would have thought it would do the same thing in your loading process.
- Even with parameter sniffing, it would likely use the seek as it seems most reasonable.

I suggest

- a) confirm the loading process is correct, and
- b) try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query in case there is a poor cached query plan

---

As an addendum, it is worth reviewing/posting the actual query plans and/or the runs with `SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON;` - and comparing good runs to bad ones. I often find the statistics run points me to problematic areas quickly, though the plan tells me what it's doing with those.

---

*Broader thoughts*

The fastest time will be the relevant covering non-clustered index (e.g., the one on Time and has all the fields you need, but no more).

The version with just a non-clustered index on Time (no other fields) would need to do a Seek-lookup process (a nested loop join) to get the rest of the data from the clustered index, one row at a time. This is probably why your performance is better with the Time non-clustered index, but is still slow (e.g., if the filtering finds 100,000 rows, it needs to go back to the clustered index 100,000 times to get the extra columns).

The non-clustered index including all the relevant fields overcomes the issue about the nested loop join - and is therefore a lot faster.

The thing that surprises me is that a clustered index read would be so much slower. If you have a useful clustered index (Time) so it can do a clustered index seek, then it shouldn't be *that much* slower. The extra time it needs would be to read all the other columns (e.g., the clustered index reads will need to read all the columns as well) but the number of rows read should be the same.

That's why I would suggest there seems to be something wrong in the process - it doesn't sound like it's doing a clustered index seek.

It is worth looking at the execution plan of the process - it may be that the insert is then taking a lot of time as it needs to sort the data before the insert (e.g., as the clustered index is not on Time, but the insert target's clustered index is ID, it would need to re-sort the data before inserting it). However, this would be the same whether it was getting the data from your covering non-clustered index, or new clustered index.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Your words about covering non-cluster index are exactly what I thought about that - we're eliminating extra time, required to look up data, by including it into the index. That is proved by the excellent results of such queries.
And yes, we were assuming the cluster index will behave the same way. I don't know how can I ensure that the index seek is indeed used during the actual loading, but when I run the queries that are used there, it is definitely used, and takes 100% of time.

Comment: Sorry - by "ensure it's being used", I mean to track it via Actual Execution Plan if you can - ensuring it's doing a clustered index seek, and that the number of rows returned is the same as the expected number of rows. If it's run by an external process, try tracking which SQL commands are being run via the SQL Server Profiler or using the XEvent Profiler from SSMS. Remember also that those % costs in plans are estimates, not actual costs - better to look at the times on the execution plans imo.

Comment: So, I've checked the SQL Profiler output - the queries use the indexes exactly as they are supposed to do - the fast one uses non-clustered seek, the slow one uses clustered seek. There are not other steps in the plan - the query is really simple.  Both of queries show approximately the same CPU counter, but the slow one makes 10 times more reads.

Comment: The clustered index includes all data (except for data stored off-row, like n/varchar(max), XML, and a few others). If you have many other large columns on the table (e.g., varchar(2000) with lots of data) then it will *still need to read those columns when reading from the clustered index, even though it doesn't use them*. As your total time seems to be reads (no CPU sorting etc) - if the non-clustered index takes 20-30 seconds, then it sounds like your clustered index version would take 200-300 seconds.

Comment: PS One of my strategies for indexing is to make a fairly generic 'info' index (e.g., IX_TableA_Info) that has the short fields that are used - numerical, dates, small varchars. Most queries don't look at the large fields - and the ones that do tend to look at very specific rows - meaning that these 'info' indexes allow the processing to work faster because of reducing the amount of data read to a fraction of what it would be if looking at the clustered index.

Comment: After reading some information on SQL Server data pages, I understand, that (n)varchar columns are located at the end of the page, and if they don't fit into the 8192 size, in a separate allocation unit. So I decided to check the behavior with numeric columns only, for the sake of the experiment. And now something weird happens with the query plan - instead of doing CI seek, it does CI scan, and then parallelize and compute scalar. So the query remains slow anyway, now because of wrong plan (?)

Comment: That sounds like the clustered index is no longer on the `time` column. That's the sort of plan you get if, say, the CI is on ID, then you're filtering by date. What it's doing is a) reading all the rows, and b) only including the rows that match your where clause.

Comment: Yes, you were right, that was my mistake, that query was running against the table with old CI, and the fields were not included into NCI.  But now I try to  run the most simple query, with just the time column - I see the CI index seek is being used, but the timing is still tens of minutes, and there are a lot of reads again. So, I assume, that the whole row is read even for the key column, and that makes the CI unusable for very long rows, like in our case.

Comment: That is correct. The CI effectively also includes all the data (except for specific types of fields like xml, n/varchar(max), etc). When you read a row from the CI, you read the whole row - it is stored together. More technically, what happens is that data is stored on the 8kB pages, with as many rows packed end-to-end as possible on each. SQL Server reads/writes pages not rows - so it must read/write the whole page. If you have a very wide table, then you won't get a lot of rows on each page. This results in a lot of pages being read.

Comment: If you have an hour or so to spare, I strongly suggest Brent Ozar's [How to think like an SQL Server Engine](https://www.brentozar.com/training/think-like-sql-server-engine/) - best video I have seen regarding indexes and their use.

Comment: If you'll add the statement about the rows and pages to the answer, I'll accept it. At least it answers the "why?" part. Thank you very much for your time!